# TinyMCE - preserve style and function of selected element

Tags: tinymce

I have decided to 'enhance' a `textarea` in a form with TinyMCE... however, doing so has interrupted the styling and jQuery functionality of the original element, as TinyMCE wraps that element in an `iframe` and a few `div`s.  What I'd love to be able to do is to get the TinyMCE functionality (preserving text formatting, etc.) but not lose the styling and functions that I had associated with the original `textarea`.  I looked through the TinyMCE documentation, but couldn't seem to find anything about this.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

My form features the `textarea` like so:

```
<head>
    <script>tinymce.init( { selector: 'textarea' } );</script>
</head>

<div class="form-element">
    <div class="label-container">
        <label for="body">Post</label><span class="warning">Please fill out this field</span>
    </div>
    <textarea id="body" class="input-field" name="body"></textarea>
</div>
```

but adding TinyMCE breaks the `label`/`textarea` relationship.

Also, jQuery functionality is broken, such as this validation script:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var inputFields = $(".input-field");
    var proceed = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++){
        if($(inputFields[i]).val() == ""){
            $(inputFields[i]).css("border", "solid 3px #E86F3A");
            $(inputFields[i]).prev().find(".warning").show();
            var proceed = false;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else{
            $(inputFields[i]).css("border", "none");
            $(inputFields[i]).prev().find(".warning").hide();
        };
     };
    //OTHER STUFF...
});
```

since the `textarea.input-field` is no longer picked up in the `inputFields` variable.

So, in a nutshell, I'm looking for the TinyMCE wrapper to 'inherit' the styling and functionality of the element that it is attached to. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly surmised when you invoke TinyMCE on a `<textarea>` the original `<textarea>` is no longer visible on the page and its replaced by an `<iframe>` and series of `<div>` elements.

If you want to keep the underlying `<textarea>` in sync you can use the `tinymce.triggerSave()` method.  This will update all of the underlying `<textarea>` elements with the current value of the appropriate instance of TinyMCE.

You can do this when someone tries to save/submit the content or you can try to perform this when certain editor events happen (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#editorevents).  Unless you need real time accuracy of the contents of the `<textarea>` its far easier to call the `triggerSave()` method right before you perform you jQuery validation.

***Note:***  Putting a border on the `<textarea>` won't have any impact on TinyMCE as you no longer see the underlying `<textarea>`.  You can certainly try to add CSS to the editor's HTML in real time.  The outer border of TinyMCE 4.4 has these classes attached:

```
class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel"
```

...but do note that these classes could change over time so if you upgrade TinyMCE check to make sure your CSS still works before upgrading.